# Function edited but still error in Prestashop

Tags: php, module, prestashop

i've tried to install a module in Prestashop called COD with fee.
On install i received this message:

> Fatal error: Access level to Inix2Module::displayWarning() must be public (as in class ModuleCore) in /home/lw1m2hta/public_html/test/ingrosso2/modules/inixframe/InixModule.php on line 3792
>   [PrestaShop] Fatal error in module file :/home/lw1m2hta/public_html/test/ingrosso2/modules/inixframe/InixModule.php:
>   Access level to Inix2Module::displayWarning() must be public (as in class ModuleCore)

So i tried to solve this problem as suggested by other people in presta forum and i went to the line and changed "protected" function to "public". The problem is that i still have the fatal error displaying in my site.

I really don't understand why prestashop doesn't check the edit. Is there a solution?

Comment: You have error not in the module `COD`, but in the module `inixframe`. Prestashop core is Ok, this error is made by the `inixframe` developers. Have you changed to `public function displayWarning($msg)`? And the error is still there?

Comment: Thank you, solved. There was another folder in modules called "inixframe" that contained same file and changed also there protected to public then worked like a charm! 
Thank you